# Server database -> client database update based on version

Tags: database, client, updates

What is the recommended method of collecting items in a server database, versioning the
database then deploying only the version differences to a client ?

Should it by a field in the table (ie. Version:  3.3.9876) against each record ?
Should it be DateTime (server based) in each record ?

And whats the best way to just deploy the changes to a client with an older version of the database ?

Is it a DUMP to a file with a Bulk import of some description ?

Open to comments.. Suggestions.

Database can be anything (firebird, mysql, sqlserver, sqlite)...

Any info greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to purchase a commercial product, RedGate's ['SQL Compare'](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) does a great job and it is intuitive to use.